# how to set batch size in curl influxdb

Tags: curl, influxdb

I want to insert more than 500,000 points to influxdb by using curl util.
so i want to set "batch size" for better performance in curl but i can't find any option about batch size.

I have already read influxdb standartd manaul section "Write Syntex" - "Write a Batch of Points with curl"

i think points.txt file's line counts in `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/write' --data-urlencode 'db=mydb&rp=myrp&u=root&p=root' --data-binary @points.txt` is batch size but i'm not sure.

so i tried to separate insert_file to 5000 lines file and insert each file to influxdb but i don't find influxdb efficient.

could anyone tell me truth ?

Comment: What are the specs of the machine you are using? What version of InfluxDB are you running?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a batch size setting in InfluxDB. All points in the file submitted via `curl` are considered one batch. Batches should be about 5k points for best throughput, although on high-power servers or with very regular data larger batch sizes can be more efficient.

> I want to insert more than 500,000 points to influxdb

That's too big to send in one batch, so you will need to split it into chunks.

> i think points.txt file's line counts in curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/write' --data-urlencode 'db=mydb&rp=myrp&u=root&p=root' --data-binary @points.txt is batch size but i'm not sure.

Yes, `cat points.txt | wc -l` will give you the number of points in the file.

> so i tried to separate insert_file to 5000 lines file and insert each file to influxdb but i don't find influxdb efficient.

There's no way to know what you didn't find efficient, so I can't respond to this. 500k points in 5k batches should take maybe 5-60 seconds on a reasonable server.